# Removing prefixes and suffixes from words in C#

Tags: c#, c#-4.0

I have a string of words and I want to remove a number of suffixes and prefixes (which are located in an array) from each word, then store back the stemmed words in a string. Is there any per-suggestion please? thanks in advance.

The total number of suffixes and prefixes is more than 100, what the better to represent them? Array? Regex? Is there any suggestion please ?

```
public static string RemoveFromEnd(this string str, string toRemove)
{
if (str.EndsWith(toRemove))
    return str.Substring(0, str.Length - toRemove.Length);
else
    return str;
}
```

This can work with suffixes, how about the prefixes? Is there a fast way to do for both suffixes and prefixes at one time? My string is too long.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Could you show some example input and the output you want?

Comment: do you have an initial code. StackOverflow is intended to collaborate with existing work, not for recommending.

Answer (score 15):

[My StringHelper class](http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/archive/2006/07/13/84942.aspx) has (among others) methods TrimStart, TrimEnd and StripBrackets,
that can be useful for you

```
//'Removes the start part of the string, if it is matchs, otherwise leave string unchanged
    //NOTE:case-sensitive, if want case-incensitive, change ToLower both parameters before call
    public static string TrimStart(this string str, string sStartValue)
    {
        if (str.StartsWith(sStartValue))
        {
            str = str.Remove(0, sStartValue.Length);
        }
        return str;
    }
    //        'Removes the end part of the string, if it is matchs, otherwise leave string unchanged
    public static string TrimEnd(this string str, string sEndValue)
    {
        if (str.EndsWith(sEndValue))
        {
            str = str.Remove(str.Length - sEndValue.Length, sEndValue.Length);
        }
        return str;
    }
//        'StripBrackets checks that starts from sStart and ends with sEnd (case sensitive).
//        'If yes, than removes sStart and sEnd.
//        'Otherwise returns full string unchanges
//        'See also MidBetween
        public static string StripBrackets(this string str, string sStart, string sEnd)
        {
            if (StringHelper.CheckBrackets(str, sStart, sEnd))
            {
                str = str.Substring(sStart.Length, (str.Length - sStart.Length) - sEnd.Length);
            }
            return str;
        }
```

Comment: but i have many suffixes and prefixes. can i put them in an array or using regex maybe? if can, how the code could be ?

Comment: Please update your question to better describe what are your requirements.Sorry, it's not clear for me.

Comment: You can keep prefixes/suffixes in 2 lists or arrays and process them similar e.g to my functions FindFirstPatternContainedInString in http://geekswithblogs.net/mnf/articles/my-listofstringshelper--class.aspx

Answer (score 0):

1. Split your string into an array of stings, each entry being each word. To do this you use `yourString.Split(',')`. Use the character separating your words in stead of `','`, it may be a spcae `' '`
2. use a foreach to check if your words have any of the prefixes or
   sufixes, to do that you use `yourWord.StartsWith("yourPrefix")` and
   `yourWord.EndsWith("yourPrefix")`
3. remove the prefix/suffix using yourWord.Replace or
   yourWord.SubString. Be carefull not to remove the prefix/sufixx if
   it's in the middle of the word!

Comment: how about the words which start or end with the suffixes and prefixes but they are not suffixes or prefixes. they just a part of that words? how can handle this issue.?

Comment: @JoneMamni mmhh... how would you distinguish words that are prefixed/suffixed from those that are not? do you have some kind of dictionary/valid_word_container variable?

Comment: @JoneMamni if your dictionary has only words that do not have prefix/suffix, then you should check if words you get on step 1 are NOT included in the dictionary, thus meaning that they are prefixed/suffixed.

Comment: @and then, it would has prefixed or suffixed?

Comment: @JoneMamni Perhaps you would need to recheck if the new word (after removing the prefix/suffix) does belong to your "valid words" dictionary. You can do that just doing `yourDictionary.Contains(yourStrippedWord)`. But yes, if I understand your problem correctly, you would have accomplished your needs.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't check from a dictionary what words are actually words then words like "premium" will be really hard to not mistake as a prefixed. Theoretically you could create somekind of rules used to check if the "mium" is an english word, but it would never be complete and would require a lot of work.